# tensorflow - map_fn to do computation on every possible combination of two tensors

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

does anyone know how to use map_fn or any other tensorflow-func to do a computation on every combination of two input-tensors?

So what i want is something like this:
Having two arrays (`[1,2]` and `[4,5]`) i want as a result a matrix with the output of the computation (e.g. `add`) on every possible combination of the two arrays. So the result would be:

```
[[5,6],
 [6,7]]
```

I used map_fn but this only takes the elements index-wise:

```
[[5]
 [7]]
```

Has anyone an idea how implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can add new unit dimensions to each Tensor, then rely on broadcasting addition:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe
tfe.enable_eager_execution()
first = tf.constant([1, 2])
second = tf.constant([4, 5])
print(first[None, :] + second[:, None])
```

Prints:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[5 6]
 [6 7]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=int32)
```