# tensorflow nested map_fn concat two tensors

Tags: tensorflow, nested

say I have two tensors:

```
a=Tensor("zeros_3:0", shape=(2, 4, 5), dtype=float32)
b=Tensor("ones_3:0", shape=(2, 3, 5), dtype=float32)
```

how can I concat each element along axis 2 to get a new tensor shaped `(2,3,4,10)`, using nested map_fn or other tf functions?

here is my for loop version

```
        concat_list = []
        for i in range(a.get_shape()[1]):
            for j in range(b.get_shape()[1]):
                concat_list.append(tf.concat([a[:, i, :], b[:, j, :]], axis=1))
```

there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47794516/tensorflow-map-fn-to-do-computation-on-every-possible-combination-of-two-tenso) using "new unit dimension", but I don't know how to use `tf.concat` with the "new unit dimension".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tf.tile` and `tf.expand_dims` with `tf.concat`. An example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.random_normal(shape=(2,4,5),dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.random_normal(shape=(2,3,5),dtype=tf.float32)

# your code
concat_list = []
for i in range(a.get_shape()[1]):
    for j in range(b.get_shape()[1]):
        concat_list.append(tf.concat([a[:, i, :], b[:, j, :]], axis=1))

# Application  method
A = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(a,axis=1),[1,b.shape[1],1,1])
B = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(b,axis=2),[1,1,a.shape[1],1])
result = tf.concat([A,B],axis=-1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    concat_list_val,result_val = sess.run([concat_list,result])
    print(concat_list_val[-1])
    print(result_val.shape)
    print(result_val[:,-1,-1,:])

# your result
[[ 1.0459949   1.5562199  -0.04387079  0.17898582 -1.9795663   0.988437
  -0.40415847  0.8865694  -1.4764767  -0.8417388 ]
 [-0.3542176  -0.3281141   0.01491702  0.91899025 -1.0651684   0.12315683
   0.6555444  -0.80451876 -1.3260773   0.33680603]]
# Application result shape
(2, 3, 4, 10)
# Application result 
[[ 1.0459949   1.5562199  -0.04387079  0.17898582 -1.9795663   0.988437
  -0.40415847  0.8865694  -1.4764767  -0.8417388 ]
 [-0.3542176  -0.3281141   0.01491702  0.91899025 -1.0651684   0.12315683
   0.6555444  -0.80451876 -1.3260773   0.33680603]]
```

**Performance**

You can use follow code to compare speed.

```
import datetime
...

with tf.Session() as sess:
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    print('#' * 60)
    for i in range(10000):
        result_val = sess.run(result)
    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    print('cost time(seconds) : %.2f' % ((end - start).total_seconds()))

    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    print('#' * 60)
    for i in range(10000):
        concat_list_val = sess.run(concat_list)
    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    print('cost time(seconds) : %.2f' % ((end - start).total_seconds()))
```

The vectorization method 10000 iterations takes `1.48s` and the loop 10000 iterations takes `5.76s` when `a.shape=(2,4,5)` and `b.shape=(2,3,5)` on my 8GB GPU memory. But the vectorization method takes `3.28s` and the loop time is `317.23s` when `a.shape=(20,40,5)` and `b.shape=(20,40,5)`.

The vectorization method will be significantly faster than the `tf.map_fn()` and python loop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! And one more question: How the performance (or efficiency) your application code is? Because my code is sooooo slow on real data. Thanks again!

Comment: @shizi I added it to the answer.